# Dynamical CSS image URLs within Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a button that can have a focus css class associated with it and I instantiate this at runtime within Javascript.
This is all provided by a bespoke Javascript framework so can not be changed.

Normally I would provided 2 additional CSS class for this button,
e.g.

```
btn { background-image: url(/btn.png);}
btn.focus { background-image: url(/btn-focus.png);}
```

This will give me 2 different images based on whether the button is 'focused' or not.

The problem I have now is that the image urls are dynamically loaded at runtime, and there is no way of specifying them with a static CSS file.

I'm thinking one possible solution is to 'somehow' generate a new style element with the btn and btn.focus classes in it (with the dynamic URLs) and either append it to the head or embedded it in the markup prior to instantation of the Button itself.  This solutions doesn't seem ideal.
Can anyone suggest anything else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Styles, including background-image can easily be changed by JS. You can simply attach a function to the onFocus event of the button that changes the background-image CSS property.

Comment: I don't have an onFocus event as such.  All I know is that when the button has focus it will contain a focus css class

Comment: A button has an onFocus event. You just need to attach a function to it however you want, this can depend on which browsers you need to support and/or what js libraries you have (jQuery for example makes it really easy), or you can use something like `element.addEventListener('focus', function() { /* change image here */ }, true)` (which btw doesn't work in older versions of IE IIRC). Read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html / http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your case is specifically about images that represent different states of a single object (e.g. focused or non-focused state of a button) then it's a good idea to use [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).
That is creating a single image with all button states and loading it (dynamically if you want).
Then you can write a universal rule in your CSS:

```
btn {background-position: 0 0;}
btn.focus {background-position: 0 -20px;} /* 20px is the height of your button*/
```

Comment: It's more that just 'states'.  I actually require different images for focused and unfocused.  I could create 2 buttons for focused and unfocus and have the .focus class include display:inline and default display:none.  But this does NOT work on a version of Maple browser - where it would display the focused image even though it has no focus class.

Comment: You can combine different images for focused and unfocused button into one image and serve it dynamically. Look at the article I linked...

Comment: It's a widely used practice and has a number of benefits. Feel free to ask if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying this doesn't work because their css styles "inline" ones are overriding your ones?  If so then do this instead

```
btn { background-image: url(/btn.png) !important;}
btn.focus { background-image: url(/btn-focus.png) !important;}
```

Comment: No. I'm saying I don't know the urls upfront and have to dynamically set then at runtime (in Javascript)